# Что такое string.digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем вообще смысл string.digits, и где в коде его вообще можно использовать. Просто вообще не ясно его назначение. Условно indigits() проверяет то, состоит ли строка только из цифр, а вот то, что делает string.digits не ясно. Идеально было бы посмотреть еще на код с использованием string.digits. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-digits/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто [строка символов, представляющих цифры](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ccdcb20cbeb1943f506a422c3fd942651389a187/Lib/string.py#L28). `string.digits[0] == '0'`, `string.digits[1] == '1'` и так далее `string.digits[9] == '9'`

Примеры использования

## Перевод числа в строку

```py
import string

def int2str(num):
    if num == 0:
        return '0'
    res=''
    if num < 0:
        sign = -1
        num = -num
    else:
        sign = 0
    while num > 0:
        digit, num = num % 10, num // 10
        # Using string.digits
        res = string.digits[digit] + res

    if sign < 0:
        res = '-' + res
    return res
```

## Генерация случайной цифровой последовательности

```py
import string
import random

def random_numstr(len:int)->str:
    char_list = random.choices(string.digits, k=len)
    return "".join(char_list)
```

Comment: Если string.digits просто переводит цифру  в строку, чем он тогда отличается от str(x)? str же тоже просто переводит в строку, только уже не цифру, а число, что еще лучше.

Comment: `string.digits = '0123456789'` - это просто [строка символов от 0 до 9](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ccdcb20cbeb1943f506a422c3fd942651389a187/Lib/string.py#L28)

Comment: Во втором примере можно показать что точно так же можно генерировать случайную последовательность из цифр и букв: `random.choices(string.digits + string.ascii_letters, k=len)`